# How can I set the decimal separator of numeric dcc.Input elements?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm working on a `dash` app which should be used in a scientific context and I want every input of numbers to be with point "." as decimal separator.
But I (and part of the users) are using German browsers. The `dcc.input` element is displayed with comma "," as a decimal separator. I want to change this to ".".

Background: The `dash_table` element is with "." as decimal separator and I want to have a consistent look of the app. Given the context, I want everything to be with dot/point as decimal separator.

I found out, how it works in html, reading this
[blog post by Daniel Aleksandersen explaining on locale of inputs in HTML](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization.html), but unfortunately there is no way to change the `lang` attribute in `dcc.input`.

How can I set set language of numeric inputs or just the whole `dash` app to default to English locale?

Here is a simple minimal example, which, in my browser (Chrome) shows with comma as decimal separator.

```py
from dash import dcc, html, Dash

# setup dash app
dashapp = Dash(__name__)

dashapp.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Input(type="number",value=0.5)
    ]
)

app=dashapp.server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dashapp.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I am in France and using English Google Chrome browser, the separator is point in the dcc.input.

Comment: Thank you, I want it to work with the German (or French or any other) browser, but the input should be with the point separator

Comment: Let me try to change the language of browser to English and see the difference

Comment: You can add this for the html.Div (lang= 'en') but unfortunately it does not work at all.

Comment: I tried it, too, doesn't work. Maybe, one could somehow change the stuff in the head-tag

Comment: I mean this : https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/header